# Counterexample that B-A can be NOT context free

Tags: formal-languages

Given that `A` is a context free language and `B` is a regular language, `B-A` can be not context free as it is equal to `B ∩ A'`, and context free languages are not closed under complement. Could you give me a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the languages

- B = { a<sup>*</sup>b<sup>*</sup>c<sup>*</sup> } -- an obviously regular language.
- A<sub>1</sub> = { a<sup>i</sup>b<sup>j</sup>c<sup>*</sup> | i > j }
- A<sub>2</sub> = { a<sup>i</sup>b<sup>j</sup>c<sup>*</sup> | i < j }
- A<sub>3</sub> = { a<sup>*</sup>b<sup>i</sup>c<sup>j</sup> | i > j }
- A<sub>4</sub> = { a<sup>*</sup>b<sup>i</sup>c<sup>j</sup> | i < j }
- A = A<sub>1</sub> ∪ A<sub>2</sub> ∪ A<sub>3</sub> ∪ A<sub>4</sub>

The A<sub>n</sub> langauges are all context-free, so their union is also context free, but the language B-A is the non-context free language { a<sup>i</sup>b<sup>i</sup>c<sup>i</sup> }

Comment: So B-A is equal to B-A1 or B-A2 or B-A3 or B-A4 ?

Comment: @MaryStar: No -- set minus does not distribute over union.

Comment: Ok... Do I have to use B-A=B∩A' ?

Comment: @MaryStar -- yes, that is the normal definition of set minus

Comment: @ChrisDodd "set minus does not distribute over union" - it's true that in general $A \setminus (B \cup C) = (A \setminus B) \cup (A \setminus C)$ does not hold, but $(A \cup B) \setminus C = (A \setminus C) \cup (B \setminus C)$ always holds.

Comment: The equivalent relation is $A \setminus (B \cup C) = (A \setminus B) \cap (A \setminus C)$.

Answer (score 3):

Just because the CFLs aren't closed under complement doesn't mean that the complement of a CFL is *never* a CFL.

As a hint: Σ* and ∅ are regular and therefore context-free.

Hope this helps!